# Stringification Parentheses Elimination

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringify

In c I have the following in an existing code base:

```
#define MYVAR (1)
```

As you can see this is conforming good practices in C by surrounding the #define with parenthesis (even though I know in this case it makes no difference since the value is not 
an expression). Regardless I would like to use this in stringification. when I do this:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TO_STRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)

const char* mystring = TO_STRING(MYVAR) ;
```

The resultant string is "(1)". I'd like to eliminate the parentheses **without** doing the simple:

```
#define MYVAR 1
```

Is there anyway to eliminate parentheses during stringification in c?

Comment: Since this is in the preprocessing phase and you've explicitly *defined* `MYVAR` as replaced-with `(1)` I don't believe what you're looking for is doable. If it is, I can't imagine it being so without being very-cpp-backend-specific.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks

Comment: I don't believe surrounding literals with brackets is necessarily good practise, it may even lead one to believe it's part of the macro syntax.

Comment: @Veltas It is *very* common practice in-part to avoid accidental side effects from macro expansions. I'm no fan of complicated preprocessor macros in the first place, but to ensure value-of rather than reference-to expansions, it is not only common, it is *advised*. (doesn't help the OP any, but its still true).

Comment: @Veltas I'm not sure I understand your question. But a simple example: Take  `#define MUL(x,y) ((x)*(y))` vs simply `#define MUL(x,y) x*y`. What happens when this is expanded with `MUL(a+1,b+2)` ? The latter becomes `a+1*b+2`, which is certainly *not* always `((a+1)*(b+2))`. The parens are simply there to squash such an unintended expansion, to *isolate* intended parameter evaluation, if you will.

Comment: Is MYVAR always an integer?

Comment: @WhozCraig: I was talking about literals. Just because it's common practise doesn't mean it's good practise. I'm not sure I see the point of surrounding literals specifically with brackets in macro definitions, it just seems cumbersome.

Comment: @Veltas In general I find its best to do it even for literals because if you don't you inevitably have a junior coder come along 3 years later, change you macro to #define MYVAR 1+1 without adding the paras. and then... But as with most style things its up for debate... just my opinion.

Comment: Good practice is to do things for a reason, to know what that reason is, and for that reason to be relevant to what you're doing. Using parentheses here is therefore *not* good practice: it is the very definition of *bad* practice by discouraging thinking about what you're doing. If a new coder comes along and does that later... hire better newbies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `STRINGIFY x` instead of `STRINGIFY(x)`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MYVAR 1

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TO_STRING(x) STRINGIFY x

int main(void)
{
    const char *mystring = TO_STRING(MYVAR);

    printf("%s\n", mystring);
    return 0;
}
```

`TO_STRING(x)` expands to `STRINGIFY (1)` when `MYVAR` is defined as `(1)`

If `MYVAR` is defined as `1` without parentheses you get a compile time error.

Comment: I've confirmed that this works but could you explain it a bit? e.g. why do we need each of these steps.